# How is screen recording different from a screenshot with respect to the way it is implemented?

Tags: screen, screenshots

To experiment I used root privileges and [Lspeed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paget96.lspeed&hl=en) to make my screen monochromatic. Then I took a screenshot, surprisingly, the image was not monochromatic but in full colour.

[image]

To prove that I actually took a screenshot with a monochromatic screen, I decided to shoot a video with a camera. But then the inbuilt screen recording feature quickly came to my mind and I decided to screen record me taking a screenshot, fully knowing the likely outcome.
I was in for another surprise when I found the screen recording to be monochrome. I've converted it to a gif given below.

[image]